# Build a custom payment gateway in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: php, magento2

Bank just gave me 2 links

first for token validation like.

sandbox url: somethingurl.

then I have to pass

```
{
    "userName":"test",
    "password":"123456Aa"
}
```

in json format

after that I have to find bank generated token from this post reguest.

which I've already done.

and then I've to send magento 2 order data (grand total) with some other credentials to a bank secure url:

somethingurl.com/createorder

json format is like this

```
{

"merchantId": "11122333",

"amount": "100",

"currency": "050",

"description": "This is test",

"approveUrl": "http://localhost/TheBankPHP_1.0.1/approve.php",

"cancelUrl": "http://localhost/TheBankPHP_1.0.1/cencel.php",

"declineUrl": "http://localhost/TheBankPHP_1.0.1/decline.php",

"userName": "test",

"passWord": "123456Aa",

"secureToken": "bd6e290e-ca3d-4a4b-b7c1-defe9ff6f7af"

}
```

Now, my question is how can I do this when user click place order button. and store that in my admin panel that order is placed with that bank order payment.

Is it possible to use cash on delivery method just set a link.

I've implemented a php page but how I integrate this with a module I've no idea. Can you please help me @Damian Culotta ?

here is my php file given below.

```
<?php
    $url = "https://sandbox.thebank.com:443/transaction/token";
    $data = json_encode(array("userName" => "test","password" => "123456Aa"));
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    # Setup request to send json via POST.

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    # Return response instead of printing.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    # Send request.
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    # Print response.
    echo "<pre>$result</pre>";

    $mydata = json_decode($result, true);

    $sectkn = $mydata["transactionId"];

    echo $sectkn;


    $turl = "https://sandbox.thebank.com:443/transaction/createorder";
    $data = json_encode(array(
    "merchantId" => "11122333",
    "amount" => "100",
    "currency" => "050",
    "description" => "This is test",
    "approveUrl" => "http://localhost/theBankPHP_1.0.1/approve.php",
    "cancelUrl" => "http://localhost/theBankPHP_1.0.1/cencel.php",
    "declineUrl" => "http://localhost/theBankPHP_1.0.1/decline.php",
    "userName" => "test",
    "passWord" => "123456Aa",
    "secureToken" => $sectkn,
    ));
    $ch = curl_init( $turl );
    # Setup request to send json via POST.

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    # Return response instead of printing.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    # Send request.
    $tresult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    # Print response.
    echo "<pre>$tresult</pre>";



$mydatat = json_decode($tresult, true);

$linkdata = $mydatat["items"];

$myurldata = $linkdata["url"];
$myorder = $linkdata["orderId"];
$mysession = $linkdata["sessionId"];


$redirect_url = $myurldata. "?ORDERID=". $myorder. "&SESSIONID=". $mysession;
header("Location: .$redirect_url");

//echo $redirect_url;

?>
```

N.B. for security purpose: I've changed the bank url. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom module to create your custom payment gateway.

I have create one for my need. You can get idea base on it.

[PayEase Payment Gateway For Magento 2](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2017/09/payease-payment-gateway-for-magento-2.html)

Comment: I've seen your code but don't get a clear idea. cause I've to first verify bank end generated token and then pass data with that token in a two different sandbox url.